# Liquid Layouts: 3 column - Fixed Fluid Fluid with px margins

Tags: css, fluid-layout, liquid-layout

This is driving me nuts! I'm trying to do a liquid layout that has a left fixed width (130px), a middle fluid column and a right fluid column, all of them with 20px margins.

Because I only want the right column to scroll when the content overflows, I've put left and middle inside a fixed positioned container .wrapper (which takes 50% of the page) and the other 50% for the right hand column. I've made the margins as borders with box-sizing.

But when I resize the browser, the middle column resizes until in disappears and the text on the left and middle column overflows.

Any ideas?

```
<head>


<style>


html, body {
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin:0;
}



html {
background-color: #555;
}


.wrapper {
padding:0;
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
position:fixed;
width:50%;
background:blue;
height:100%;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
border:20px solid white;
}

.middle {

background:yellow;
height:100%;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
border-left:150px solid white;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}




.right {
float: right;
width:50%;
height:100%;
background:pink;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
border-right:20px solid white;
border-top:20px solid white;
border-bottom:20px solid white;
}





.left {
float:left;
width:130px;
background:green;
height:100%;
margin-right:20px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>

<div class="middle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>

</div>

<div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>





</body>
```

I've also done this on jquery, but I seem to be running into the same resizing problems. Can anyone shed some light on this issue? Many thanks!

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>



<style>
html, body {width:100%;margin:0; padding:0;}

html {  overflow-y: scroll;}




.middle {
position:fixed;
background:yellow;
left:170px;
top:20px;
margin-right:20px;
}

.left {
position:fixed;
left:20px;
top:20px;
background:blue;
width:130px;
margin-right:20px;
}

.right {
float:right;
margin: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
background:blue;
width:50%;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="left">Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello </div>
<div class="middle">Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello </div>


<div class="right"></div>



<script>

$(document).ready(function () { /* standard jQuery document ready */
$('.left').css('height', '100%').css('height', '-=40px');
$('.middle').css('width', '50%').css('width', '-=170px');
$('.middle').css('height', '100%').css('height', '-=40px');
$('.right').css('height', '100%').css('height', '-=40px');
$('.right').css('width', '50%').css('width', '-=40px');

});



$(window).on('resize', function(){


$('.left').css('height', '100%').css('height', '-=40px');
$('.middle').css('width', '50%').css('width', '-=170px');
$('.middle').css('height', '100%').css('height', '-=40px');
$('.right').css('height', '100%').css('height', '-=40px');
$('.right').css('width', '50%').css('width', '-=40px');

});





</script> 

</body>
```

Comment: I am unsure what exactly you want the right column to do?

Comment: Right column is 50% of the total window width and scrolls on content overflow. The other half (the left half) is 50% of total window width– with fixed positioning–and contains the left column (at 130 px width with 20px right margin) and the mid column with a 20px right margin. The Jquery version I've posted is the right display, only that I want a min-width for the liquid columns or the body, so that the columns don't keep resizing until they disappear.

Comment: see latest jsfiddle below

Comment: Thanks DreamTek! Still, mid position should be fixed so that right scrolls only, so I can't have a wrapper for both mid and right together. Also when I resize, mid and right go behind left, any way to prevent this from happening? Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry friend I am having difficulty visualizing what you want to achieve. Also in my examples below mid and right do not go behind left.

Comment: Hi DreamTek.. I've updated your jsfiddle to illustrate the issue. In this case, if the right column is 1400px height (because it will have overflowing content) I'd like to scroll (using the html scroll, not a scroll on the div), but I would like for middle to stay where it is, just like the left col. And if I resize the window to it's smallest width, when I scroll left to right, mid column disappears behind left col. Any way of fixing this? Hope it makes sense.. Many thanks!  bhttp://jsfiddle.net/m/rwv/

Answer (score 1):

## LIQUID LAYOUTS NO PROBLEM

---

If you provide additional requirements I can easily tweak the code below to accommodate.

**HTML**

```
<div class="Lft">
  LEFT CONTENT
</div>
<div class="RgtContent">
  <div class="Mid">
    MID CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="Rgt">
    RIGHT CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Lft{
    height:100%;
    background:#b00;
    position:fixed;
    width:130px;
}
.RgtContent{        
    width:100%;
    margin-left:130px;
}
.Mid{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    background:#0b0;
    width:50%; 
}
.Rgt{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    background:#00b;
    width:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7nQMx/

---

**EXAMPLE WITH PADDING / MARGINS**

Margins are not part of the box-sizing model, 
however a wrapper with padding around the desired div with margins has the same effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/7nQMx/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="Lft">
LEFT CONTENT
</div>
<div class="RgtContent">
  <div class="RightWrapper">
    <div class="Mid">
      MID CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="Rgt">
      RIGHT CONTENT
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Lft{
    height:100%;
    background:#b00;
    position:fixed;
    width:130px;
}
.RightWrapper{
   margin-left:130px; 
}
.RgtContent{    
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.Mid{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    background:#0b0;
    width:50%; 
}
.Rgt{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    background:#00b;
    width:50%;
}
```

---

To have the right column scroll simply set a height and overflow property:

```
.Rgt{
    height:500px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7nQMx/3/

Comment: Thank you! But the right and mid columns cannot be wrapped together because right needs to scroll and mid needs to be fixed. The only 2 that could be wrapped are left and mid, I suppose?

Comment: Please clarify your desired column layout.
I understood it as:
Left fixed width position. 
Mid liquid width scroll. Right liquid width scroll

Comment: It's: Left fixed width AND fixed position. Mid liquid with fixed position. Right liquid with scroll. I was guessing that putting a min-width on the body would do the trick but the liquid columns keep resizing even after that? Thank you.

Comment: That also works but I have the scroll set on the html and it works fine. It's not really a scroll problem, it's a window resizing issue where the middle column just keeps scaling down and the text overflows even if I set a min-body width.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a start for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/S4mxM/

```
<div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="middle">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div>

    <div class="right">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
padding: 0;
margin:0;
}

html {
background-color: #555;
}
.left, .middle, .right, .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    background: blue;
    margin-left: 150px
    width: auto;
}
.left {
    background: green;
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
}
.middle, .right {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.middle {
    background: yellow;
}
.right {
    background: pink;
}
```

I rewrote the whole code

Comment: Thank you! But I have the same issue with the wrapping as above: can't wrap middle and right because right needs to scroll and mid needs to stay put, just like left. Any ideas?